# GitHub API create commit

Tags: json, http, github, commit

I need help with GitHub API,

I need commit new version of file through API, I'm trying to achieve this by sending post request to

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:username/:repo:/git/commits/
```

with data

```
{
    "login": "username",
    "token": "auth_token",
    "parent_commit": "sha",
    "message": "commit message.",
    "content": {
        "path": "full/path",
        "mode": "edit",
        "data": "new content"
    }
}
```

But it fails with result - not found.

Have anyone idea where to send this request and if this format is right?

(Format is inspired by - http://swanson.github.com/blog/2011/07/23/digging-around-the-github-api-take-2.html)

Answer (score 8):

Note that since May 2013, you have a [CRUD API available](https://github.com/blog/1498-file-crud-and-repository-statistics-now-available-in-the-api):

That includes a [file update API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-or-update-a-file)

```
{
  "message": "my commit message",
  "committer": {
    "name": "Scott Chacon",
    "email": "schacon@gmail.com"
  },
  "content": "bXkgdXBkYXRlZCBmaWxlIGNvbnRlbnRz",
  "sha": "329688480d39049927147c162b9d2deaf885005f"
}
```

(with content being the updated file content, Base64 encoded.)

Answer (score 6):

> Committing new content is actually a multi-step process, using their low level and powerful API

Actually, since Sept. 2021 (9 years later), it is not, but using the GraphQL [GitHub API v4](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql) (instead of the [GitHub API v3](http://GitHub%20API%20v3))

See:

> ### [A simpler API for authoring commits](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-09-13-a-simpler-api-for-authoring-commits/):
>
> The new GraphQL mutation [`createCommitOnBranch`](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#createcommitonbranch) makes it easier to add, update, and delete files in a branch of a repository.
>
> This new API offers a simpler way to commit changes compared to the existing [Git database REST APIs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git).
> With the new `createCommitOnBranch` mutation, you do not need to manually create blobs and trees before creating the commit. This allows you to add, update, or delete multiple files in a single API call.
>
> Commits authored using the new API are automatically GPG signed and are [marked as verified](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/managing-commit-signature-verification/about-commit-signature-verification) in the GitHub UI. GitHub Apps can use the mutation to author commits directly or [on behalf of users](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps#user-to-server-requests).

```bash
$ curl https://api.github.com/graphql \ 
       -s -H "Authorization: bearer $TOKEN"
       --data @- <<GRAPHQL | jq \
         '.data.createCommitOnBranch.commit.url[0:56]'
{
  "query": "mutation (\$input: CreateCommitOnBranchInput!) {
    createCommitOnBranch(input: \$input) { commit { url } } }",

  "variables": {
    "input": {
      "branch": {
        "repositoryNameWithOwner": "demo-githubs/test",
        "branchName": "main"
      },
      "message": {"headline": "Hello from GraphQL!" },
      "fileChanges": {
        "additions": [{
            "path": "GraphQL.md",
            "contents": "`echo 'Hello, GraphQL! | base64`"
        }],
        "deletions": [{ "path": "REST.txt" }]
      },
      "expectedHeadOid": "git rev-parse HEAD"
}}}
GRAPHQL
```

[image: graphql]

---

> Can I set up a committer using the api?

Yes, you should be able to set up a bot as a committer in GitHub actions, but not using the API.

As noted by [沙漠之子](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7488424/%e6%b2%99%e6%bc%a0%e4%b9%8b%e5%ad%90) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301989/github-api-create-commit/69290756#comment136452274_69290756):

> Currently, [API v4's `CreateCommitOnBranch`](https://studio.apollographql.com/public/github/variant/current/schema/reference/objects/Mutation#createCommitOnBranch) explicitly does not support setting the committer.
> API v3 creates commits with signatures, and must set the private key.
> See "[Creating a signed commit via API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64861557/6309)".

Without API:

When you utilize a GitHub action to commit files, the default committer is the GitHub Actions bot. However, you can customize the committer by setting the `git` user and email before making the commit.

In your GitHub action workflow file (e.g., `.github/workflows/main.yml`), you can configure the `git` user and email before making the commit.

```yaml
name: Committer Action

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Configure git
      run: |
        git config user.name "Your Bot Name"
        git config user.email "bot@example.com"

    - name: Make a commit
      run: |
        echo "New Content" > file.txt
        git add file.txt
        git commit -m "Commit by bot"
        git push
```

That way, the bot will be recognized as the committer for any changes pushed through this action.

Comment: Facing this for a first commit --->
"Argument 'expectedHeadOid' on InputObject 'CreateCommitOnBranchInput' has an invalid value (\"`git rev-parse HEAD`\"). Expected type 'GitObjectID!'."

Comment: @ranit Yes, probably because your first commit does not have parent. Can you confirm this works for a commit on top of existing commits?

Comment: Banging my head at this one as well. How can one get the value for expectedHeadOid using the Graphql API? (See question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72836597/how-to-create-new-commit-with-the-github-graphql-api)

Comment: Can I set up a committer? It seems that no relevant information was found. I want to use bot as committer in GitHub action.

Comment: @沙漠之子 I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: @VonC Sorry for the ambiguity of my question, what I meant was that when creating a commit using the api is it possible to set a committer

Comment: Currently, API v4's `CreateCommitOnBranch` explicitly does not support setting the committer. https://studio.apollographql.com/public/github/variant/current/schema/reference/objects/Mutation#createCommitOnBranch. API v3 creates commits with signatures, and must set the private key. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64861557/7488424

Comment: @沙漠之子 Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibillity.

Answer (score 4):

I puzzled over this one too!

Committing new content is actually a multi-step process, using their low level and powerful API.

Here is [a gist](https://gist.github.com/2935203) I made to share one solution.  Note that a few things are hard coded, like the branch name "master".

Please feel free to fork and improve the gist, or let me know if you're having trouble getting this to run.