# How to commit to github repository without a local git repository?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I set up an asp.net core project and right now I want to use a github repository which could be synchronized with my current project. Is any chance to commit all changes to a github repository without initialize a local repository for an existing project? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Git is designed as a distributed version control system—so you have a local repository and zero or more remotes, each of which is in some sense "equal".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Just felt online version control will be more secure if there is a system crash.

Comment: Security has nothing to do with it, and having a local repository does nothing to limit what's on GitHub. I _strongly_ urge you to work with a local repository. There are countless benefits (again, this is how Git was designed to work). Even GitHub's official app creates local commits and then pushes them to GitHub.

Comment: You are right that nothing hurt if I keep a local repository, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github API create commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301989/github-api-create-commit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add each files manually to the github repo directly by uploading it. But why do you want to do such a thing.?

Comment: Thanks. Seems there is not a direct way to achieve this.