# What sites are using my GitHub hosted script?

Tags: javascript, html, github

Suppose I have a JavaScript script named `foo.js` in a GitHub repo. I need to know what sites (domains) are using this script. Thus, for instance, if a website `www.example.com` is referencing my script...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://myGitHubRepo/foo.js"></script>
  </head>
  etc...
</html>
```

I'd like to get, track or list `example.com` as a domain. To be more clear, I don't want to track actual users visiting `www.example.com` nor their IPs nor anything like this, I just want to track or make a list of the sites (domains) referencing my script in their HTMLs. Is that possible?

---

PS: some hypothetical solutions and their problems:

1. The first idea that comes to mind is using an analytics tool; however, despite being the owner of my code, I'm not the owner of the site containing the repo: GitHub is the owner. Therefore, using an analytics tools seems to be impossible.
2. I can't do calls to my server: again, I don't have a server, it's a GitHub repo.
3. A simple `window.location.hostname` in the script would get what I want, but it would get it on the client side. I don't know if it's possible sending that information back to me... actually, I don't even know if that is legal.

Comment: you can make ajax request from the script to your server?

Comment: the simplest solution would be to host the script on your own server - then it's simple :p

Comment: @JaromandaX so, using GitHub, I assume there is no solution, is that right?

Comment: Yes, there is a really simple solution, as @iRohitBhatia points out. But I guess many people using the script will wonder why there is made a call to a foreign server.

Comment: @davidkonrad but I don't have a server (*"you can make ajax request from the script to **your** server?"*), the library is in a GitHub repo. That's my issue.

Comment: not directly related, but sort of directly related, you can publish to npm and see statistics for usage of your library

Comment: I just want to note sneaking a beacon in your js code like that is kind of rude.  I'd be upset if someone did that to me.  Although not reading the code before using it, I guess I kind of deserved it.

Comment: @Megapteranovaeangliae BTW: Most people wont use your github repo anyway, since it is a real performance killer. Typically you will clone the project or use a real CDN. Perhaps there are paid CDN's which provide info about domains using the script?

Comment: Look at https://help.github.com/en/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/listing-the-projects-that-depend-on-a-repository and see an example here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize this is the closest you can get using just GitHub.

Comment: @user120242 yes, it's quite rude... and, as I wrote in my question, I don't even know if it is legal.

Comment: What license covers your javascript and repo?

Comment: @Sean Apache 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without addressing the legal aspect, you could <del>embed [PAT (Personal Access Key)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) in your script</del>, which would enable said script to make GitHub API calls.

Typically: "[Create or update a file (`PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`)](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-or-update-a-file)" (I [mentioned it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16412371/6309))

You would replace the content of a file in a dedicated user/repository with the domain name you get from the script.
Each version of that file would represent one instance of the script execution, with the associated domain written in it.

The drawback is that anyone could use that key for accessing the repository, so you need to monitor its content and usage carefully (again, using a dedicated user account/repository just for that one usage).
As noted below by [bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8705432/bk2204), this is too insecure.

Instead of a PAT, you can adopt a similar workflow as a GitHub webhook: your script would call a dedicate URL, with a JSON event, which would then register the call.

Comment: Besides the fact that this is wildly insecure, if you check this token into a repo, GitHub will probably flag it as compromised with their token scanning tools.  _And_ that account may be able to be used for abuse if anyone gets ahold of that token.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it. Telemetry is tricky - and people will opt to not use your script.

Also without "place" to gather this information you cannot do it on github.

You can try leveraging "code" search engines like:
 https://publicwww.com/
 https://www.nerdydata.com/

and similars