# How to create new commit with the github graphql API?

Tags: github, graphql

I am trying to create a new commit using the github graphql api, using the [createCommitOnBranch](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-09-13-a-simpler-api-for-authoring-commits/) mutation.
What value should one use for expectedHeadOid: "?????"?
How can one get such value from the Graphql API?

This is my attempt so far:

```
{
mutation m1 {
  createCommitOnBranch(
    input: {
      branch: 
      {repositoryNameWithOwner: "some_repo/some_owner",
        branchName: "main"
      },
      message: {headline: "headline!"},
      fileChanges: {
        additions: {path: "README.md", contents: "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="}
      }
      expectedHeadOid: "?????"
    }
  ) 
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be the parent commit of the new commit you want to create.
Hence the `"expectedHeadOid": "git rev-parse HEAD"` which prints the SHA1 hash of `HEAD` (`HEAD` of the remote repository on top of which you want to append a new commit using [a mutation `createcommitonbranch`](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#createcommitonbranch), and [its endpoint](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/input-objects#createcommitonbranchinput)).

> `expectedHeadOid` (GitObjectID!)
> The git commit oid expected at the head of the branch prior to the commit.

[In octokit](https://github.com/octokit/graphql-schema/blob/03a3c40ae9770fc1f1ff98c077baa7aca68707e1/schema.d.ts#L3063-L3064=), it is described as:

> The git commit oid expected at the head of the branch prior to the commit.

[Carl Brasic](https://github.com/brasic) shows in his gist "[createCommitOnBranch error example](https://gist.github.com/brasic/964dfc371d524a09d602745ae3b238ff)" what happens if you pass an out of date `expectedHeadOid` value

> We are *intentionally* telling the API to append a commit to the branch only if the tip is a value that we know it is not.
> Assuming this clone is up to  date with the remote this will always fail with a descriptive error.
>
> ```
> expectedHeadOid=`git rev-parse HEAD~`
> ```

Error:

```
"message": "Expected branch to point to \"f786b7e2e0ec290972a2ada6858217ba16305933\" 
            but it did not.  Pull and try again."
```

---

[This example](https://iq.opengenus.org/api-requests-in-java/#apirequestforfileuploadorreupload) uses a first query (`defaultBranchRef` ) to get the parameter value for the second one (`CreateCommitOnBranchInput`), useful when you don't have a locally cloned repository:

> Step 1. Query the OID of the last commit to the branch, as it is required to make a commit.
> Example graphQL query is shown below:

```
{
  repository(name: "my-new-repository", owner: "AnnaBurd") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 1) {
            nodes {
              oid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Step 2. Use graphQL mutation called "`CreateCommitOnBranchInput`" to create a commit with new file content:

```
----------------------mutation ------------------
mutation ($input: CreateCommitOnBranchInput!) {
  createCommitOnBranch(input: $input) {
    commit {
      url
    }
  }
}

-----------variables for mutation---------------
{
  "input": {
    "branch": {
      "repositoryNameWithOwner": "AnnaBurd/my-new-repository",
      "branchName": "main"
    },
    "message": {
      "headline": "Hello from GraphQL!"
    },
    "fileChanges": {
      "additions": [
        {
          "path": "myfile.txt",
          "contents": "SGVsbG8gZnJvbSBKQVZBIGFuZCBHcmFwaFFM"      <------- encoded base 64
        }
      ]
    },
    "expectedHeadOid": "db7a5d870738bf11ce1fc115267d13406f5d0e76"  <----- oid from step 1
  }
}
```

Comment: So impressed, you are a legend! I was able to accomplish step 1. with the following: {repository(name: "my-new-repository", owner: "AnnaBurd") { {
    object(expression: "main") {
      oid
    }
  }. Is there any meaningful delta between the solutions? Is there any good resource to learn this API?

Comment: @Oded Great, did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @Oded Sorry, I did not see at first our edited comment.

Comment: @Oded Beside the [official GitHub GraphQL explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer), and its [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/forming-calls-with-graphql), a GraphQL playground can be useful to play around with this: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-playground (you have [a all collection of them](https://github.com/topics/graphql-playground)). https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-tester could help too.

Comment: Yes I did, with either your Step 1. or the one I added in comment above. The links you shared are great, but am not see how they lead to knowing how to reach the great solution you shared: https://iq.opengenus.org/api-requests-in-java/#apirequestforfileuploadorreupload. Guess it is time for my first Medium post